# Symfony2 Pre populate form with data from model?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a ProfileType as follows:

```
namespace Site\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {       
        $builder->add('facebook', 'text', array('required'=>false))
            ->add('myspace', 'text', array('required'=>false))
            ->add('twitter', 'text', array('required'=>false))
            ->add('soundcloud', 'text', array('required'=>false))
            ->add('youtube', 'text', array('required'=>false))
            ->add('website', 'text', array('required'=>false))
            ->add('bio', 'textarea', array('required'=>false));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'profile';
    }
}
```

and I want to pre populate the form fields with data that is already in the database so it is visible in the form.

My controller:

```
namespace Site\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Site\UserBundle\Entity\Profile;
use Site\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileType;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function editAction()
    {           
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $editprofile = $em->getRepository('SiteUserBundle:Profile')->findOneByUser($user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId());

        $form = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(), $editprofile);

        $form->bindRequest($this->getRequest());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $editprofile->setUpdated(new \DateTime("now"));
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('SiteUserBundle_login'));
            }

        return $this->render(
            'SiteUserBundle:Default:editprofile.html.twig', 
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I thought this way would be easier to update a users profile.

Comment: Please confirm 1) the $editprofile is valid and 2) put $form->getData() after $form->isvalid and check that it has the valid form data.

Comment: Yes. Everything is fine. I just want to pre populate the form input with data from the database. Maybe I should assign variables and send them to view.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
findOneByUser($id)
```

by

```
find($id)
```

Also try passing the $id as a slug from url to your Action. url: example.com/page/id

```
sampleAction($id){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before to bind:

```
$editProfile->setSomething... // the stuffs from the database
$form->setData($editProfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only bind the request to the form if the form was actually submitted.

```
if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
    $form->bindRequest($request);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dumping $editprofile, check what it returns, it should return all the profile contents. in your case the row for the particular id